# Get the user id of the user you are viewing (as admin)

Tags: drupal, admin

I'm logged in as admin, and go to view a user's account page.  How can I get the id of the user I'm viewing, rather than the $user->uid (which would be the admin user id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user's ID is in the URL of the user edit form.

http://example.com/user/1/edit

If you have the devel module installed (and you should), there'll also be a devel tab on the user's profile page that'll let you see other information about the user.

If you're talking about the user's profile *template* (i.e. you're overriding `user-profile.tpl.php`), the user you're viewing is in the `$account` variable.

Comment: +1 That's some good points, though you should be careful with devel on a production site.

Comment: I was talking about the template, sorry not to clarify, and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Devel module and you will get every kind of information you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

do a print_r($node) in the correct file or use devel like Vivek suggested